# Convert Object to string and back

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to convert Javascript object to string and then this string back to object.

Objects i get like that:

```
    var Checked = {};

// Hold all checkboxes
    $('div.list input[type=radio]:checked, input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
        var $el = $(this);
        var name = $el.attr('name');
        if (typeof (Checked[name]) === 'undefined') {
            Checked[name] = [];
        }
        Checked[name].push($el.val());
    });
```

I know how to do this with array by using join and split, but how to be with objects?
Now how to convert this object to string?
How to get back this string to object?

Comment: `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: JSON supported in vanilla Javscript?

Comment: Yes it is https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin JSON : JavaScript Object Notation

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin : JSON.parse and JSON.stringify are javascript functions. They are independent of any library/framework.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you are:

```js
var object = {
  "1": [1, 2, {
    3: "3"
  }]
};
var str = JSON.stringify(object);
console.log(str);
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(obj["1"][2][3]);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The **`JSON.parse()`** method parses a string as a JSON object, optionally transforming the value produced by parsing.

**Syntax**

JSON.parse(text[, reviver])

**Parameters**

text
    The string to parse as JSON. See the JSON object for a description of JSON syntax.
reviver Optional
    If a function, prescribes how the value originally produced by parsing is transformed, before being returned.

**Returns**

Returns the Object corresponding to the given JSON text.

**Throws**

Throws a SyntaxError exception if the string to parse is not valid JSON.

---

The **`JSON.stringify()`** method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is specified, or optionally including only the specified properties if a replacer array is specified.

**Syntax**

JSON.stringify(value[, replacer[, space]])

**Parameters**

*value*

```
The value to convert to a JSON string.
```

*replacer* (Optional)

A function that alters the behavior of the stringification process, or an array of String and Number objects that serve as a whitelist for selecting the properties of the value object to be included in the JSON string. If this value is null or not provided, all properties of the object are included in the resulting JSON string.

*space* (Optional)

A String or Number object that's used to insert white space into the output JSON string for readability purposes. If this is a Number, it indicates the number of space characters to use as white space; this number is capped at 10 if it's larger than that. Values less than 1 indicate that no space should be used. If this is a String, the string (or the first 10 characters of the string, if it's longer than that) is used as white space. If this parameter is not provided (or is null), no white space is used.

Source:

- [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)
- [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = { x: 5, y: 6 };
var a = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(typeof a);
console.log( a);
var b = $.parseJSON(a);
console.log(typeof b);
console.log( b);
```